# How to change the default folder for uploading file in jboss

Tags: jboss

I am trying to upload a file, I am trying to change the default location of the uploaded file. How to change this please suggest ?

```
package Controller;

import java.io.File;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.PrintWriter;  
import java.util.Iterator;  
import java.util.List;  

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

import requests.Connect;
import display.DisplayLog;
/** * Servlet implementation class ControlServlet
 */
public class ControlServlet extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    boolean result;
    private boolean isMultipart;
    private String filePath;
    private int maxFileSize = 1000 * 1024;
    private int maxMemSize = 1000 * 1024;
    private File file ;

    public ControlServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**     
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        HttpSession session=request.getSession();
        String userName = request.getParameter("username");
      isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
        response.setContentType("audio/mpeg3;audio/x-mpeg-3;video/mpeg;video/x-mpeg;text/xml");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter( );

        if (isMultipart) {  
            // Create a factory for disk-based file items  
            FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();  
            // Create a new file upload handler  
            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);  
           try {  
              // Parse the request  
              List items = upload.parseRequest(request);  
             Iterator iterator = items.iterator();  
             while (iterator.hasNext()) {  
               FileItem item = (FileItem) iterator.next();  
               if (!item.isFormField())  
                {  
                 String fileName = item.getName();      
                 if (fileName != null) {
                     fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(fileName);
                 }
                 String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");  
                 root = "F/images";
                 File path = new File(root + "/uploads");

                 if (!path.exists())  
                  {  
                   boolean status = path.mkdirs();  
                 }  
                 File uploadedFile = new File(path + "/" + fileName);  
                 System.out.println(" Prashant File Upload Location is "); 
               //  System.out.println(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());  
                 System.out.println("fileName is " +fileName);
                 System.out.println("root is " + root);
                 System.out.println("path is " + path);
                  if(fileName!="")  
                  {   
                      item.write(uploadedFile);  
                      System.out.println(" Prashant File Upload Location 2 is "); 
                      System.out.println(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());  
                      out.println("<h1>File Uploaded Successfully....:-)</h1>");
                  }
                  else
                  {       
                     out.println(uploadedFile.getAbsolutePath());  
                      out.println("<h1>File Uploaded Successfully....:-)</h1>");
                      System.out.println("file not found");  
                  }

               }  
                else  
                {  
                  String abc = item.getString();  
                }  
             }  
           } catch (FileUploadException e) {  
                 out.println(e);  
           } catch (Exception e) {  
                 out.println(e);  
           }  
         }  
          else  
          {  
            out.println("Not Multipart");  
          }          
        System.out.println("print this Prashant" + userName);
        session.setAttribute("username",userName);
        request.setAttribute("username","prashant");
    //  RequestDispatcher myDispatch = request.getRequestDispatcher("Index.jsp");
        //myDispatch.forward(request, response);
}

}
```

I am getting this as default folder F:\jboss-4.2.3.GA-jdk6\jboss-4.2.3.GA\bin\ please help i am new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
 String root = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

you are setting the upload path to the containers path, not a default path but the place where the server started from.  You can make the upload path anything you want it to be, it depends on your needs and configuration.
You could create a system property with the directory of your choice, you could set it as a dynamic property in a JBoss configuration file (not sure what that would be for JBoss4).